# Where does the apostrophe go when the noun is modified by "both"?

Tags: punctuation, possessives, apostrophe

"As both of my grandfather’s alma mater," vs. "As both of my grandfathers' alma mater," — which is correct?

Comment: Would you say "Both of my grandfather was there", "Both of my grandfathers was there"  or "Both of my grandfathers were there"?

Comment: The expression you ask about can be recast as "As the alma mater of both of my grandfather/grandfathers." Whether to use _grandfather_ or _grandfathers_ in this case shouldn't be a difficult choice—and yet the only difference between that wording and the form you ask about is that your form expresses the possessive as an apostrophe or apostrophe-_s_ attached to the noun _grandfathers_ or _grandfather_, instead of as "of my grandfather/grandfathers".

Answer (score 2):

If you mean to refer to one school attended by your two grandfathers, then you would use the usual plural possessive forms, regardless of the presence of "both".  That would produce "As both of my grandfathers' alma mater," leading into whatever you were about to say about the school.

However, I would like to add that this sentence structure is unclear and may lead the reader to wonder if you are referring to both grandfathers or, as is common in this world, you have mis-typed and actually meant to say "both of my grandfather's alma maters," referring to one man's two schools, or "both of my grandfathers' alma maters," referring to the two schools attended, respectively, by the two men.  I'm not entirely certain what you meant, myself.

Overall, it might be better to re-word the sentence for the sake of clarity.  If my first guess was correct, then perhaps "As the alma mater of both of my grandfathers," or something similar.